# how to get data from intersection of 2 SQL tables to php

Tags: php, sql

I want to take data from intersection of 2 SQL tables. I tried this

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, Name, Hostel FROM Student, HostelName WHERE Student.hostel_ID = Hostel.hostel_ID";
```

But it Did not work.
I also tried this too.

```
$sql = "SELECT Student.ID, Student.Name, Hostel.HostelName FROM Student, Hostel WHERE Student.hostel_ID = Hostel.hostel_ID";
```

How can I fix this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean :

```
$sql = "SELECT Student.ID, Student.Name, Hostel.HostelName FROM Student INNER JOIN Hostel ON Student.hostel_ID = Hostel.hostel_ID";
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the fact that `hostel_ID` is the only attribute which is common between the two tables, you can do `NATURAL JOIN` on common attribute `hostel_ID` to achieve the desired result,

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, Name, Hostel FROM Student NATURAL JOIN HostelName";
```

Here's the reference:

- http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/advance-query-in-mysql/mysql-natural-join.php

Comment: thanks that works well, and its very easy to impliment.